# Simplest way to derive from NSArray

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

How would you approach a problem of deriving new `NSArray` from existing `NSArray` by removing certain element from original one? I know of `NSMutableArray` class, but I'd like to know an approach of *least moving parts*.

In *Deriving arrays* section of `NSArray` documentation, there are methods like `arrayByAddingObject:` or `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:`. However there are no methods for deriving new arrays by removing certain objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about the next to method listed: `–filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` `–subarrayWithRange:`?

[`–filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJJDBEB) will return a new array with objetcs matching the criteria defind by the predicate.

[`–subarrayWithRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange%3a) will give you a subarray for a certain range

Answer (score 3):

You filter arrays to get rid of items.

so:

```
filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
```

seems to fit your needs. You'll need to provide a predicate, which can be anything you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new array using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method based on your criteria.

Also you can get NSIndexSet containing indexes of objects you want to keep using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` method and then create new array from original using `objectsAtIndexes:` method.